# switch geth from --syncmode=full to --syncmode=snap

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a node that has been running with `--syncmode full`. It's been offline for a month and is now far behind. Can I switch the flag to `--syncmode snap` to increase the speed of recovery? Is there a possibility that this switch will corrupt geth's internal state?